# Activity is never launched when the notification is clicked on android version 4.0

Tags: java, android, notifications

Here is the implement code of the notification:

```
Notification notification = new Notification();
RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),
                                          R.layout.status_bar_ongoing_event_progress_bar);
// ignore the setup code for expanedView
notification.contentView = expandedView;
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent,
                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
mNotificationMgr.notify(notification_id, notification);
```

This code works fine on android device 2.2, however, this doesn't work on android  device 4.0. When user click the notification, the MyActivity is not launched, and nothing happens.

I don't know what's the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know exactly what the problem in your code, but if you use the code from  [android Dev](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

it's work flowless on **ICS** and **pre ICS**

i lately check this code